# Write $\tan (\arcsin b)$ in terms of $b$.

Tags: trigonometry

I have posted my attempt as a answer. *(see below)*

I mostly just need verification.

---

*More specifically...*

**Did I get the $\pm$ right? Is it needed? In what cases should the answer be negative?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\arcsin b=y\implies-\dfrac\pi2\le y\le\dfrac\pi2\implies\cos y\ge0$ and $\sin y=b$

$\cos y=+\sqrt{1-b^2}$

$\tan(\arcsin b)=\tan y=\dfrac b{\sqrt{1-b^2}}$

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

### Solution

---

**Part 1**

$ \alpha = \arcsin b$

$ b = \sin \alpha $

---

**Part 2**

$
\tan (\arcsin b) = 
\tan \alpha = 
\frac{\sin \alpha}{\cos \alpha} = 
\frac{\sin \alpha}{\pm\sqrt{1-\sin^2{\alpha}}} =
\frac{b}{\pm\sqrt{1-b^2}}
$

---

### Answer

$$ \tan (\arcsin b) = \pm\frac{b}{\sqrt{1-b^2}} $$

Comment: You should include your **attempt** in your question instead of self-answering your own question.