# Write $\cos (\arctan b)$ in terms of $b$.

Tags: trigonometry

*Yesterday, I submitted a similar [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1844412/write-tan-arcsin-b-in-terms-of-b). I'm pretty sure I understood the solution posted by @labbhattacharjee, however I want to make sure I got this problem correct.*

---

### Postscript

Since commenters @shaihorowitz and @Winther said I was correct, I have posted my attempt as an answer.

---

Comment: WA verifies your answer  http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Cos%5BArcTan%5Bx%5D%5D

Comment: @shaihorowitz -- Thanks, I didn't think of using WolframAlpha. I suppose I'll turn my attempt into an answer.

Comment: @Winther -- Isn't that why I have the "$\pm$"?

Comment: I was thinking of the step right under "Step 2:". However I was sloppy in reading you answer as on the line above you say $\alpha\in[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$ so this is not a problem. My bad, I'll remove the comment!

Comment: @Winther -- No problem - it happens to the best of us (and more often to the worst of us, such as myself `:)`). Although, I was momentarily dumbstruck that after the previous problem I solved (linked in my question) that I never actually understood it in the first place. `:)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\cos\arctan b>0$, because $-\pi/2<\arctan b<\pi/2$. If $t=\cos\arctan b$, then
$$
\frac{1}{t^2}=\frac{1}{\cos^2\arctan b}=1+\tan^2\arctan b=1+b^2
$$
Therefore
$$
t=\sqrt{\frac{1}{1+b^2}}
$$

Comment: So, my "$\pm$" is not needed?

Comment: @SirJony No, it's wrong

Comment: OK, thank you! Looks like you and @YvesDaoust are the only ones who removed it.

Comment: @SirJony $\cos(\arctan b)$ cannot be negative. If you know that $x>0$ and $x^2=2$, then $x=\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Yes, I see. I've always had a hard time analyzing domains, especially when it comes to trigonometry.

Answer (score 1):

For those, like Sir Jony, who don't like to memorize formulas, try this:
  Draw a right triangle.  Label one angle $\theta$, the leg next to that angle, 1, and the leg opposite, b.  By the Pythagorean theorem (**that** I can remember!), the hypotenuse has length $\sqrt{b^2+ 1}$. Since $tan(\theta)= $ "opposite side over near side" $= \frac{b}{1}= b$, $arctan(b)= \theta$.  Then $cos(arctan(b))= cos(\theta)= $ "near side over hypotenuse $= \frac{1}{\sqrt{b^2+ 1}}$

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{1-\cos^2(\arctan b)}{\cos^2(\arctan b)}=\tan^2(\arctan b)=b^2$$

giving, by inversion

$$\cos(\arctan b)=\pm\frac1{\sqrt{b^2+1}}.$$

By the definition of the arctangent, $b>0$ yields an angle in the first quadrant, with a *positive* cosine, and $b<0$ third quadrant, also with a *positive* cosine.

Answer (score 0):

Use the formula $\displaystyle\frac{1}{\cos^2 x}=1+\tan^2 x$ instead, which we can rewrite as $\displaystyle\cos x =\pm\sqrt{\frac{1}{1+\tan^2 x}}$.

Use the substitution $x=\arctan b$:
\begin{equation}
\cos(\arctan b) =\pm\sqrt{\frac{1}{1+\tan^2 (\arctan b)}}=\pm\sqrt{\frac{1}{1+b^2}}
\end{equation}
$\tan(\arctan b)$ equals $b$ for $\underline{\textrm{every}}$ real number $b$.

Comment: I suppose that works, too. However, I'm not one to memorize those more complicated formulas, so I stuck to elementary identities.

Comment: That formula is very handy anyway.

Comment: Yes, it probably is. Thank you very much, though!

Comment: The formula will help you to memorize the derivative of the tangent function $y=\tan x$:
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{d\tan x}{dx}=1+\tan^2 x = \frac{1}{\cos^2 x}
\end{equation}
The same can be said for the derivative of $y=\cot x$:
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{d\cot x}{dx}=-(1+\cot^2 x) = -\frac{1}{\sin^2 x}
\end{equation}

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

---

**Step 1:** Solve for $\cos \alpha$ as much as possible

let $ \alpha = \arctan b $; $ -\frac{\pi}{2} \le \alpha \le \frac{\pi}{2}  $

$ b = \tan \alpha = \frac{\sin \alpha}{\cos \alpha}$

$ \cos \alpha = \frac{\sin \alpha}{\tan \alpha} $

---

**Step 2:** Find relation between $b$ (i.e. $\tan \alpha$) and $\sin \alpha$

$ \tan \alpha = \frac{\sin \alpha}{\cos \alpha} =  \frac{\sin \alpha}{\sqrt{1 - sin^2{\alpha}}} $

$ \sqrt{1 - sin^2{\alpha}} \tan \alpha = \sin \alpha $

$ (1 - sin^2{\alpha}) \tan^2 \alpha = \sin^2 \alpha $

$ \tan^2 \alpha - sin^2\alpha \tan^2 \alpha = \sin^2 \alpha $

$ (1 + \tan^2 \alpha)\sin^2 \alpha - \tan^2 \alpha = 0 $

$ (1 + b^2)\sin^2 \alpha - b^2 = 0 $

$ \sin \alpha = \frac{\pm\sqrt{-4(1 + b^2)(-b^2)}}{2(1+b^2)} = \frac{\pm2b\sqrt{1 + b^2}}{2(1+b^2)} =  \pm\frac{b}{\sqrt{1 + b^2}} $

---

**Step 3:** Return to solving for $\cos \alpha$

$ \cos \alpha = \frac{\sin \alpha}{\tan \alpha} = \frac{\pm\frac{b}{\sqrt{1 + b^2}}}{b} = \pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + b^2}} $

---

### Answer

$$ \cos (\arctan b) = \pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + b^2}} $$

Answer (score 0):

Why not resort to the trig function definition and draw a right triangle opposite side $b$, adjacent side $1$, calculated hypotenuse $\sqrt{1+b^2}$ and so it follows that $cos$ of this angle is $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+b^2}}? $ With the $ \sqrt .. $ sign it has to be always $ \pm.$